# How to derive formula from GLM coefficients?

Tags: r, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model

I get the following coefficients from a logistic glm but need to convert it into a formula, i.e. Y= b0 + bx1 + bx2...

[image]

My challenge is that the variables are discrete and each missing a category: OSHIGH, highcHIGH, highpHIGH, altregionDK. How do I get the coefficients for these variables or create a formula including all?

Comment: I think indicator variables can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that R is using one level of each categorical predictor as a reference level. You can actually derive your values from your current output, but I believe you can also get explicit output by forcing regression through the origin with formula = Y ~ X1 - 1 (of course adapt this to fit your use case).